# JaCoCo plugin gives different coverage

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm using the JaCoCo Maven plugin and agent to measure and retrieve the code coverage data of an application which is tested nightly.
This is the schema of the architecture:

[image: Tests architecture]

My Maven project is configured with the [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) to execute some API tests during the Maven `verify` phase.
The Maven command executed by the Jenkins server is the following

```
mvn verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:dump sonar:sonar -Djacoco.address=TEST_SERVER -Djacoco.destFile=/proj/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec -Dsonar.projectKey=sonar_test -Dsonar.projectName=sonar_test -Dsonar.branch=sonar_test -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=/proj/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco -Dsonar.language=java
```

As you can see first the tests are executed through the `verify` phase, then the `jacoco:dump` goal retrieves the coverage data from the test server (I configured the server to run the JaCoCo agent) and at last the data is uploaded to my Sonar server.

The "strange" behaviour I'm having is that if I run this command on my computer and then on Jenkins (configuring the Jenkins project accordingly) in the SonarQube page I get different coverage results. Moreover, if I configure the Jenkins project and then I simply COPY it creating a new (but equivalent) Jenkins project, the results are different.

[image: Coverage result for local test]

[image: Coverage result with Jenkins]

I tried different configurations and cases, but I cannot understand what the problem can be. Am I not considering some JaCoCo constraints (e.g. someting related to the Jenkins project name)?

Comment: few details - how do you pull the code to jenkins for the project and what is the result difference(how and where do you see that)?

Comment: @nullpointer The Jenkins project is configured to pull the code at each execution through the "Source Code Management" step. [Example](http://benhallbenhall.dimbal.biz/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/hudson-source-code-management.png)

Comment: There is no difference between the local and the pulled copy as no one pushes anything on the project

Comment: I meant *different coverage results*, what is the difference that you see. Please update the question.

Comment: Updated, I meant different coverage results in the SonarQube project page in the two cases.

Comment: Are the pom.xml (and the parent pom.xml files) on your computer and the server the same?  Having a different JaCoCo configuration in them could lead to different results.

Comment: @gvdm Since its the ITs, would be curious to know what classes do you exclude and include during jacoco reporting and how the jacoco plugin is configured to report the details against which code?

Comment: @toongeorges the projects are the same as they are cloned from the same Git repository at the same time. Anyway, no JaCoCo configuration is written in the pom.xml; the plugin is confiugred only through the `mvn` call parameters

Comment: @nullpointer on the server side the JaCoCo agent is configured through the JAVA_OPTS configurations of the WildFly test server in this way: `javaagent:/path/to/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6300,includes=my.package.*`. The (placeholder) `my.package.*` is the pattern of the packages of my project

Comment: Couple of notes from me (as JaCoCo developer): class files that are used during report generation should match class files (be the same) that were instrumented on your test server for generation of `jacoco-it.exec` - check that. Drilling down in two different reports simultaneously you can pinpoint classes that lead to difference of the overall value - can be used for further debugging.

Comment: @Godin if the classes on the server and the ones used during report generation (local machine or Jenkins) must be the same then I cannot use this kind of architecture for code coverage of tests, right? Because the WAR file on the server is never the one compiled when starting the tests and the report generation..

Comment: And so...Should I follow this workflow for code coverage of remote tests?

1. Maven compile and package
2. Deploy of the generated WAR on the remote server (e.g. using Ansible)
3. Run the remote tests without recompiling the wars (but is the Maven `verify`phase able to not run the `package` phase?)
4. retrieve (dump) the JaCoCo coverage data

Comment: As was said earlier - remote server should run classes that later will be analyzed to generate report. Such match is required, because otherwise there is no guarantee that report shows exactly what was executed. See http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html for more details. And excuse me, but your setup is quite complex, so hard to tell precisely how to achieve this for it.

Comment: Thank you @Godin for your answer. I will try the worlflow I supposed in my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700428/jacoco-plugin-gives-different-coverage#comment70626169_41700428) and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the question comments, the artifact deployed on the test server and the one compiled during the `verify` phase on which the report is generated must be exactly the same, so it is not enough that the code is the same.

To solve my problem I had to implement this workflow with Jenkins:

1. Do a `mvn package` on the project
2. Deploy the generated WAR on the remote server using Ansible (we already use Ansible for nightly deploys and other tasks on remote machines)
3. Run the remote tests without recompiling the wars. To do this I had to add the  Maven flag `-Dmaven.compiler.useIncrementalCompilation=false` (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330518/how-to-stop-mavens-verify-phase-rebuilding-the-artifact) and [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) for the hints) in order to not re-compile the artifacts during the `verify` phase
4. Retrieve (`dump`) the JaCoCo coverage data

So the Maven command described in the question has been split in two commands: the one which creates the package and the one which performs the tests and retrieves the JaCoCo data without recompiling the artifacts.